# is it possible to oversell KVM VPS?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, vps

I found a cloud service provider selling VPS with a cheaper price compared to other companies. They claim to use kvm for virtualization so it made me curious is overselling hardware the reason of this price difference and is this possible on KVM?

Comment: It's possible to overprovision your hardware using *any* virtualization tool. This has nothing to do with KVM in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible
Further reading [here](https://www.hostdime.com/blog/kvm-vs-openvz/)